# AssertionError while putting value in chronicle map

Tags: java, chronicle, chronicle-map

I'm trying to use chronicle map as off heap map for my project. When I try to put a value in the chronicle map, I'm getting the below error.

This error comes when `searchStatePresent()` is true. I don't know what is this and there is not much information available.

Does anyone have any idea?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
        at net.openhft.chronicle.map.impl.CompiledMapQueryContext.putNewVolatile(CompiledMapQueryContext.java:3975)
        at net.openhft.chronicle.map.impl.CompiledMapQueryContext.putEntry(CompiledMapQueryContext.java:3990)
        at net.openhft.chronicle.map.impl.CompiledMapQueryContext.doInsert(CompiledMapQueryContext.java:4176)
        at net.openhft.chronicle.map.MapEntryOperations.insert(MapEntryOperations.java:153)
        at net.openhft.chronicle.map.impl.CompiledMapQueryContext.insert(CompiledMapQueryContext.java:4099)
        at net.openhft.chronicle.map.MapMethods.put(MapMethods.java:89)
        at net.openhft.chronicle.map.VanillaChronicleMap.put(VanillaChronicleMap.java:901)
```

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: @tgdavies oh wow, thank you for your help and for being so generous. Can you please edit it also? I would love to see how you would have asked it. It'll help me for sure.

Comment: I can't edit it, as I don't have access to your code. You need to edit your question and add a complete, minimal, reproducible example which illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests there is an inconsistency, possibly in your hashCode/equals.

The map attempted to find the key but couldn't find it initially, however when it went to insert the key/value it found it was already there.

Comment: Thanks Peter but my key is Integer. My map looks like this Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>

Comment: @RituBhandari are you able to include a simple unit test to reproduce this? Ideally here https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/issues